# Save one form as well as generate a value in Outputid(primary key) which is in another form at a time?

Tags: java, mysql

I've two forms  named

1. Input form and its table name is Input (Fields :Input_id,Input_name,Output_id)
2. Output form and its table name is Output(Fields :Output_id,Output_name)

I am going to First save the Input form so it must save the Input table data as well as  generate a data  as 1 (for next record 2, 3 ,4 and so on)
on output_ID(primary key) in the Output table at one time on click of save button.

so on click of one save buton(which is in Input form), Output id(primary key ) should generate in Output table 
as well as it should be store in Input table as a foriegn key?

Is it possible to do such scenario?anyone reply

Comment: could you please clarify your question a bit more giving some examples of what you want.

Comment: i want to link input table and output table.. i.e on click of button ..input table data must get save as well as it must generate a outputid value which is in output table 

here, output id is a foriegn key to input table and primary key to output table. so outputid value should come in both input and output table on click of save button.

is that possible ?

or it is must to fill output table to link to Input table with outputid

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong , on click of save button you are going to send `input name` and `output name` to your `api`.

`MySQL doesn't support multi-table insertion in a single INSERT statement`

So in your `API` code you should first

1. Save output name in Output_table.
2. Get the id of the row of Output_table
3. Write another query that will take this `output_id` and `input name` and save it to `input table`.

`You should fill output table to link to Input table with output id`